# I want to do calculation between different items when id is the same in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following data.

```
id  type  
1   15
1   16
2   10
3   10
3   11
3   13
3   14
4   9
5   8
5   20
5   21
5   22
```

Using the above data, we want to calculate the "interval" when "id" is equal.

```
id  type interval
1   15    -
1   16    1
2   10    -
3   10    -
3   11    1
3   13    2
3   14    1
4   9     -
5   8     -
5   20    12
5   21    1
5   22    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group by 'id' and take the `diff` to create the 'interval' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, interval := c(0, diff(type)), by = id]
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(interval = c(0, diff(type))
```

---

Or with `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$interval <- with(df1, ave(type, id, FUN = function(x) c(0, diff(x))))
```